# How to Know if Virtual Machine is stopped in Azure

Tags: java, node.js, rest, azure, azure-virtual-machine

I am using the Azure Rest API. How can I check if a virtual machine is running or stopped? for first I thought to use the provisioning State, but it gives no useful info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can using the Virtual Machine REST API `Get information about a virtual machine` for Azure Resource Management, please refer to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/azure/mt163682.aspx.

In the response of the REST API for `Get information about the instance view of a virtual machine`, you can find an attribute `displayStatus` of the second element in the json property `"statuses"` array the the bottom of the reference page, see the picture below:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try the code below. PowerState is what you need to check.

```
       using (ComputeManagementClient computeClient = new ComputeManagementClient(credentials))
        {
            HostedServiceListResponse services  = await computeClient.HostedServices.ListAsync();
            foreach(HostedServiceListResponse.HostedService service in services.HostedServices)
            {
                DeploymentGetResponse deployment = await computeClient.Deployments.GetBySlotAsync(service.ServiceName, DeploymentSlot.Production);

                var powerState = deployment.RoleInstances[0].PowerState;

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see the status of VM on the portal itself. If you want to use powershell- `Get-azurevm -servicename "svcname" -vmname "vmname"`

will give you status of vm as well.

Answer (score 0):

using Nodejs:

```
var msRestAzure = require('ms-rest-azure');
var azArmCompute = require('azure-arm-compute');
const clientId = "xxxx";
const appSecret = "xxxx"; 
const tenantId = "xxxx";
const subscriptionId = "xxxx";

let credential = await msRestAzure.loginWithServicePrincipalSecret(clientId, appSecret, tenantId);
computeClient = new azArmCompute.ComputeManagementClient(credential, subscriptionId);
var getVMStatus = async function(resourceGroup, vmName){
    try {
        await computeClient.virtualMachines.get(resourceGroup, vmName, {expand: 'instanceView'},function(err, result){
            context.log("VM Status:" + result.instanceView.statuses[1].displayStatus);
        });
    } catch (error) {
        context.log("Error has occurred while trying to get VM info");
        throw error;
    }
}

getVMStatus("Rg_xxxx","Vm_xxxx");
```

Status will be: "VM deallocating","VM deallocated","VM stopping","VM stopped","VM starting" or "VM running"
[Virtual machines lifecycle and states](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/states-lifecycle)